# Trying to access an object from a listener python web framework

Tags: python-asyncio, sanic

Pretty new to asynch so here is my question and thank you in advance.
Hi All very simple question I might be thinking too much into.

I am trying to access this cassandra client outside of these defined listeners below that get registered to a sanic main app.

I need the session in order to use an update query which will execute Asynchronously. I can definetly connect and event query from the 'setup_cassandra_session_listener' method below. But having tough time figuring how to call this Cassandra session outside and isolate so i can access else where.

```
from aiocassandra import aiosession
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from sanic import Sanic
from config import  CLUSTER_HOST, TABLE_NAME, CASSANDRA_KEY_SPACE, CASSANDRA_PORT, DATA_CENTER, DEBUG_LEVEL,  LOGGER_FORMAT


log = logging.getLogger('sanic')
log.setLevel('INFO')


cassandra_cluster = None


def setup_cassandra_session_listener(app, loop):
    global cassandra_cluster

    cassandra_cluster = Cluster([CLUSTER_HOST], CASSANDRA_PORT, DATA_CENTER)
    session = cassandra_cluster.connect(CASSANDRA_KEY_SPACE)

    metadata = cassandra_cluster.metadata

    app.session = cassandra_cluster.connect(CASSANDRA_KEY_SPACE)
    log.info('Connected to cluster: ' + metadata.cluster_name)

    aiosession(session)
    app.cassandra = session


def teardown_cassandra_session_listener(app, loop):
    global cassandra_cluster
    cassandra_cluster.shutdown()


def register_cassandra(app: Sanic):
    app.listener('before_server_start')(setup_cassandra_session_listener)
    app.listener('after_server_stop')(teardown_cassandra_session_listener)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example that should do what you need. It does not actually run Cassandra (since I have no experience doing that). But, in principle this should work with any database connection you need to manage across the lifespan of your running server.

```py
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import text

app = Sanic()


class DummyCluser:
    def connect(self):
        print("Connecting")
        return "session"

    def shutdown(self):
        print("Shutting down")


def setup_cassandra_session_listener(app, loop):
    # No global variables needed

    app.cluster = DummyCluser()
    app.session = app.cluster.connect()


def teardown_cassandra_session_listener(app, loop):
    app.cluster.shutdown()


def register_cassandra(app: Sanic):
    # Changed these listeners to be more friendly if running with and ASGI server
    app.listener('after_server_start')(setup_cassandra_session_listener)
    app.listener('before_server_stop')(teardown_cassandra_session_listener)


@app.get("/")
async def get(request):
    return text(app.session)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register_cassandra(app)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The idea is that you attach to your `app` instance (as you did) and then are able to simply access that inside your routes with `request.app`.